# Object not found error make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the directory structure as **src/ obj/ include/ bin/** I have created 2 **.cpp** file in **src** folder and a header file used by both cpp file in **include** folder. I want to create object file in **obj** folder and binary in **bin** folder below:

```
   vpath %.cpp src

   vpath %.h include

   vpath %.o obj

  all : main.o factorial.o run


  run : main.o factorial.o
      cc $^ -o bin/$@ -lstdc++ 

  main.o : main.cpp functions.h 
      cc -c $<  $(inc) -o obj/$@ -lstdc++

 factorial.o : factorial.cpp functions.h
      cc -c $<  $(inc) -o obj/$@ -lstdc++

 clean :
      rm -rf bin/* obj/*
```

**and while making first time following is the output:**

```
  betatest@dragon make-tut]$ make

     cc -c src/main.cpp  -I include -o obj/main.o -lstdc++

     cc -c src/factorial.cpp  -I include -o obj/factorial.o -lstdc++

     cc main.o factorial.o -o bin/run -lstdc++ 

     cc: main.o: No such file or directory

     cc: factorial.o: No such file or directory

     make: *** [run] Error 1

betatest@dragon make-tut]$
```

**If i run make again then no error:**

```
[betatest@dragon make-tut]$ make
cc obj/main.o obj/factorial.o -o bin/run -lstdc++
```

**What is the problem?**

Comment: **Sir!!!! then like I have to write run: obj/main.o obj/factorial.o ; cc $^ -o bin/$@ -lstdc++; and remove the line vpath %.o obj**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule of makefiles. Targets need to create a file with the **exact** name of the target.

So all your rules (e.g. `main.o : main.cpp functions.h ; cc -c $<  $(inc) -o obj/$@ -lstdc++`) that generate files in a directory but do not include that directory in the target name are incorrect.

This causes the problem in the first run as make believes it has created `factorial.o` and `main.o` but it has actually created `obj/factorial.o` and `obj/main.o`.

The second run the `vpath` directives you have written are in play and make correctly finds the `obj/factorial.o` and `obj/main.o` objects under the bare `factorial.o` and `main.o` names.

Comment: Fix your makefile. You need `obj/factorial.o`, etc. targets and prerequisites. Then you don't need the `vpath %.o obj` line either.

Comment: @Ethan Reisner **Sir !!! One more help . Please describe a real time situation where vpath can be used as I did that I could refer next time. Please sir!!!!**

Comment: vpath is for finding *sources*. http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/